# Requisição AJAX com formulário está atualizando a página

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo um simples formulário para ser enviado com jQuery Ajax.
Os dados estão sendo enviados, mas está atualizando a página normal.

Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo errado, pois no envio do formulário a página está sendo atualizada, mas eu gostaria que isso não ocorresse.

Segue os códigos:

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".enviamensagem").submit(function (){     
    $(".listamensagem").html("<h4>Carregando Mensagens</h4>");      
    var formdata = $(".enviamensagem").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"dados.php",
        data: formdata,
        beforeSend: function(){
        },
        success:function(data){           
          $("#areamsg").html(data);           
        }
    });
});
```

});

HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="enviamensagem">
    <fieldset>        
      <label >Escrever Mensagem: 
          <textarea name="mensagem" required></textarea></label>               
          <input type="submit" class="botao" id="btnenviamsg" value="Enviar" />           
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Altere seu `.submit(function(){...` para  `.submit(function(e){...` e adicione logo no inicio da function `e.preventDefault();` antes de `$(".listamensagem")...`, acho que resolve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O clique no botão de submit é um evento do próprio browser, ele deve ser anulado para utilizar um ajax. Existem diferentes formas de fazer isso.

**e.preventDefault()** - funciona na maioria dos casos, mas não previne a execução de outros handlers que podem estar associados.

```
$(".enviamensagem").submit(function(e){ 
    /* qualquer código */

    e.preventDefault();

    /* qualquer código */
});
```

**e.stopPropagation()** ou **e.stopImmediatePropagation()** - interrompe o evento da forma correta no jQuery, pq interrompe todos os handlers do jQuery relacionados ao botão.

```
$(".enviamensagem").submit(function(e){ 
    /* qualquer código */

    e.stopPropagation();

    /* qualquer código */
});
```

Os métodos jQuery acima podem ser utilizados em qualquer parte do código da função, porém é recomendado que utilize logo no começo da função.

Lembrando que é importante colocar o nome da variavel de evento como parametro da função,conforme o exemplo: function(**e**), senão não irá funcionar.

**return false** - interrompe o evento em javascript nativo, o que NÃO respeita os handlers específicos do jQuery e em DOM2 não funciona.

```
$(".enviamensagem").submit(function(){ 
    /* qualquer código */

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o `event.preventDefault()` ou então dar um `return false` na função do `submit`. Isso serve para prevenir a submissão da página

Veja:

```
$(".enviamensagem").submit(function (e){     
   e.preventDefault();
   // resto do código
});
```

Ou:

```
$(".enviamensagem").submit(function (e){     
    // resto do código

    return false;
});
```